# How to change backgroud color of nz-range-picker?

Tags: angular, web, antd, ng-zorro-antd

New to web development, and new to using ng-zorro.

In my project, I'm using `nz-range-picker` of `ng-zorro`. I want to change the default color to my customed color.

HTML sample code:

```
    <nz-range-picker [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" [(ngModel)]="date"
        [nzPlaceHolder]="[t('fault.date_start'), t('fault.date_end')]" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    </nz-range-picker>
```

`ant-calendar` doesn't work, I even couldn't use F12 to inspect the related elements...

```
::ng-deep .ant-calendar {
  background-color: rgba(36, 40, 48, 1);
  color: white;
}
```

My question is how to How change background color of nz-range-picker? The actual effect picture go to the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N7MT.jpg).

And a more common question is how to use chrome F12 to inspect the related instantly elements since it disappears fastly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Color of which part of the `nz-range-picker` do you want to change? The Input? Or the calendar component? Could you provide at least a piece of your code or rather a stackblitz link or something?

Regarding your second question. Debugging components that dismiss immediately after focus lost is quite tricky but possible. I am using the chrome Debugger for it.

1. Open the Developer console (`F12` in Chrome)
2. Go to the Sources tab
3. Open the calendar on the `nz-range-picker`
4. Press the `F8` key (key to pause the debugger)
5. You can inspect the calendar element now.

Comment: @Galis, I tried your solution to catch the pop-ups of the calendar, but it fails, still appreciated that.